# using sparse matrix in R error

Tags: r

```
 sparseMatrix(i = svd[[1]], j = svd[[2]], x = svd[[3]])
  Error in validObject(r) :
```

invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: all column indices (slot 'j') must be between 0 and ncol-1 in a TsparseMatrix

I have a dataset like below

```
id p1  p2   p3   p4
a  10  20   30   40 
b  32  45   65   54
c  54  56   12   45
d  21  34   65   44
```

Comment: Try `with(svd, sparseMatrix(p1, p2, x=p3))`

Comment: Error in validObject(r) : 
  invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: all row indices (slot 'i') must be between 0 and nrow-1 in a TsparseMatrix

Comment: Not getting an error with a data.frame.  Check below.  I used the row/col indices as p1 and p2, and the x values as p3

Comment: It is not clear from your post, what the expected output would be. Please make it clear. Also, sparseMatrix takes row/column indices as first and second arguments. I don't know what the ids are supposed to do here.

Comment: From `?sparseMatrix` documentation  `i,j: integer vectors of the same length specifying the locations
          (row and column indices) of the non-zero (or non-‘TRUE’)
          entries of the matrix. `  In your dataset, it is not clear which is the row and column id and the corresponding values.

Comment: > library('Matrix')
> N = sparseMatrix(i=x[[1]],  j=x[[2]],  x=x[[3]])


> object.size(N)
1188937848 bytes

> nnzero(N)
[1] 99072112

Comment: something similar to the above ...replicate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80855/discussion-between-saugandh-datta-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(Matrix)
library(reshape2)
svd$id <- as.numeric(factor(svd$id))
sM <- transform(melt(svd, id.var='id', na.rm=TRUE), 
              variable=match(variable, names(svd)[-1])) 
with(sM, sparseMatrix(id, variable, x=value))
```

#### data

```
svd <- structure(list(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), p1 = c(10L, 32L, 54L, 
 21L), p2 = c(20L, 45L, 56L, 34L), p3 = c(30L, 65L, 12L, 65L), 
p4 = c(40L, 54L, 45L, 44L)), .Names = c("id", "p1", "p2", 
"p3", "p4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: i have multiple id's and multiple columns , how can i use it for that